# Why is division producing a negative number?

Tags: haskell, integer, prime-factoring

Why is this printing the negative number -147982099 instead of 8462696833 = 600851475143 / 71

```
import Data.List

smallFactor n = case (elemIndex 0 (map (mod n) [2..])) of
                    Just x -> x + 2

main = print( quot n (smallFactor n) )
    where n = 600851475143
```

The full output:

```
$ ghc --make p3; ./p3
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( p3.hs, p3.o )
Linking p3 ...
-147982099
```

Comment: Could be integer overflow? Have you tried typing `smallFactor` to work with `Integer` types (instead of `Int` which may overflow...).

Comment: Duplicates (years old) of this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20700233/3088138, http://stackoverflow.com/q/6544573/3088138

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you are telling it a negative number (assuming you are using a 32 bit GHC).

```
where n = 600851475143 -- n = -443946297
```

notice:

```
Prelude Data.Int> 600851475143 :: Int32
-443946297
```

Comment: So how does Haskell determine what integer type to infer to use given that `quot :: Integral a => a -> a -> a` and `smallFactor :: Integral a => a -> Int` are polymorphic?

Comment: Luqui covered tihs.  If you still have questions after seeing luqui's answer then feel free to post another comment to either of us.

Answer (score 11):

Haskell usually defaults to `Integer` when there is a free choice of integral type to use. But here we are seeing `Int`.  And the reason is:

```
elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
```

So `x` in `Just x -> x + 2` is an `Int`, which means `smallFactor` has to return an `Int`, which means `n` in `main` has to be an `Int` because `quot :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`.

This is a good reason to use explicit type signatures.