# empty list on recursive function

Tags: haskell, tail-recursion

Im trying do some work on [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) for fun, but I got stuck now on an problem and want to move on but cant seem to get my function working. Im trying to get count the primefactors of a given integer. The function works on smaller numbers such as 13195:

```
> primeFactor 13195
[29,13,7,5]
```

But when I run a bigger number such as 600851475143:

```
> primeFactor 601851475143
[]
```

This seems really weird to me. I know haskell is a lazy language, but I don´t think it should be that lazy...

```
primeFactor' :: Int -> [Int]
primeFactor' n = [ p | p <- primes' [] [2 .. n], n `mod` p == 0 ]
   where primes' :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
         primes' ys [] = ys
         primes' ys (x:xs) | x `notMultipleOf` ys = primes' (x:ys) xs
                           | otherwise            = primes' ys xs                                                                                         

-- helper function to primeFactor'
notMultipleOf :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
notMultipleOf n [] = True
notMultipleOf n xs = and [n `mod` x /= 0 | x <- xs]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Int` has 32 bits you can't store that number (use `Integer`).

On the other hand, you can use `Data.Numbers.Primes` (and [see code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primes-0.2.1.0/docs/src/Data-Numbers-Primes.html#primeFactors)):

```
> primeFactors 601851475143
[3,3,23,1009,2881561]
> primeFactors 600851475143
[71,839,1471,6857]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an integer overflow error. The `Int` type can only represent numbers up to `2^31 - 1`

```
>> maxBound :: Int
2147483647
```

The number you entered overflows --

```
>> 601851465143 :: Int
556043703
```

On the other hand, if you use the `Integer` type there is no overflow --

```
>> 601851465143 :: Integer
601851465143
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I don't know why you obtained an empty list....  or anything at all.

You are using a brute force method to find a list of primes, dividing all numbers by all smaller primes than it.  This scales like n^2.

How long should this take to complete?

```
N^2 ~= (601851475143)^2 ~= 10^22 operations
```

It is a bit better than this, because the density of primes drops, but not much....  Let's shave off a factor of 10^2 to account for this.  On a modern 8 core 4GHz machine (assuming 1cpu cycle per operation....  way optimistic), this should take

```
10^20 operations / (10^10 operation/sec) = 10^10 sec ~= 300 years
```

to complete.

You might want to look for a new algorithm.